# Error with custom button that works with apex method

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I have a custom button in a salesforce page, and I want that when I click it, an apex method is executed. 
I follow the tutorial [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/button_1.htm) but I get an error when I click it:

> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/package/DevisToFacture}createFacture, please check the WSDL for the service.', }

Here is the javascript I put when I created the custom button :

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
var result = sforce.apex.execute("QuoteToInvoice","createInvoice",{idQuote:"{!Quote.Id}"});
alert(result);
window.location.reload();
```

My apex class is named `QuoteToInvoice` (it is a `public with sharing class`), the method is named `createInvoice` and it has a parameter `idQuote` whose type is `Id`.

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class must be `global`, `global with sharing`, or `global without sharing`, and the method must be `webservice static`. This is in the [Apex in AJAX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm) documentation.